# Please help me translate this message

Tags: translation

Please help me translate this message. What does it mean in English?

> 得了考前放弃症 可能无药可救了。

So here is the situation. I have been seeing this girl for about almost a year now and today we went out and she bought me a medicine. I told her I'm sick because I think I smoke too much. Night time comes and I saw her post a message on social media saying “”得了考前放弃症 可能无药可救了“”. My translation was stop it before the test sickness, maybe next time there is no medicine for it anymore. My question is, is she telling me to stop smoking or telling me to stop courting her?

Answer (score 2):

Wrong 证, should be 症

得了考前放弃症可能无药可救了
get 'before-exam-give-up-sickness' possible no medicine can help

I always get pre-exam nerves and want to give up, it's possible there is no medicine which can help that.

I think your love life is not in danger!

Answer (score 0):

考前放弃症 means:

- Pretest abandonment or
- Abandonment before examination

In particular, 症 means disease, or syndrome.

The message means:

> I've got pretest abandonment, perhaps incurable

It is no more serious than a joke, I think. In your case, her message is not correlated with the story happened between you.

Answer (score 0):

To me it seems like she is just making a joke. It means that she just has some type of exam coming up and is saying there is no cure for her despair/nervousness.